# Modal implemented with react-hook-form throws error related to refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Having the following component:

```
import { useToggle } from '../shared/hooks';
import { Modal, SelectInput, Textarea, Footer, Button } from '../shared/ui-components';

export function MainComponent() {
  const [isOpened, toggleModal] = useToggle(false);
  const options = [
    { id: '0', name: 'Test' },
    { id: '1', name: 'Test 2' }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={toggleModal} />
      <Modal
        title='modal title'
        open={isOpened}
        onClose={toggleModal}
        footer={<Footer onSubmit={toggleModal} onCancel={toggleModal} editMode={true} />}
      >
        <div>
          <SelectInput label='name' initialSelectedOption={options[0]} options={options} />
          <Textarea label='description' />
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainComponent;
```

How it is now, it opens a modal when the button is clicked, you can select a value from a dropdown (SelectInput) and write some input text (Textarea). `onSubmit` just closes the modal for the moment.

What I want to do, `with react-hook-form` is to be able to store those values, of the selected dropdown and input inside textarea.

So there was imported useForm, yup for validating the data, for `onSubmit` it was added `onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}`.

Here is the code after adding those:

```
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup'; // added 
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as yup from 'yup'; // added  

import { useToggle } from '@oam/shared/hooks';
import { Modal, SelectInput, Textarea, Footer } from '@oam/shared/ui-components';

const schema = yup.object().shape({ // added schema
  name: yup.string().required(),
  description: yup.string().required()
});

export function MainComponent() {
  const [isOpened, toggleModal] = useToggle(false);
  const options = [
    { id: '0', name: 'Test' },
    { id: '1', name: 'Test 2' }
  ];

  const { handleSubmit, register } = useForm({ // added useForm
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });

  const onSubmit = (data: unknown) => { // added onSubmit that should log the content
    console.log('data: ', data);
    toggleModal();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        title='modal title'
        open={isOpened}
        onClose={toggleModal}
        // added below onSubmit
        footer={<Footer onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} onCancel={toggleModal} editMode={true} />}
      >
        <div>
          <SelectInput
            label='name'
            initialSelectedOption={options[0]}
            options={options}
            {...register('name')} // added register here 
          />
          // added register also here
          <Textarea label='description' {...register('description')} />
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainComponent;
```

But when I open the modal, this error appears in console:

> react_devtools_backend.js:4045 Warning: Function components cannot be
> given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use
> React.forwardRef()?
>
> Check the render method of `MainComponent`.
> at Textarea (http://localhost:4200/main.js:47767:5)
> at div
> at div
> at div
> at div
> at div
> at OpenClosedProvider (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:4813:20)
> at TransitionChild (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:3713:27)
> at Child (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:3897:79)
> at div
> at div
> at DescriptionProvider (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:145:72)
> at ForcePortalRoot (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:4847:18)
> at Group (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:2563:22)
> at Portal (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:2527:16)
> at ForcePortalRoot (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:4847:18)
> at StackProvider (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:4888:23)
> at Dialog (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:289:20)
> at OpenClosedProvider (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:4813:20)
> at TransitionChild (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:3713:27)
> at Transition (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:3838:20)
> at Modal (http://localhost:4200/main.js:45752:5)
> at div
> at div
> at CalculationEngine (http://localhost:4200/main.js:6618:69)
> at I18nextProvider (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:119005:19)
> at CalculationEngineContainer
> at Route (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:127414:29)
> at Suspense
> at main
> at div
> at App (http://localhost:4200/main.js:148:75)
> at Router (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:127043:30)
> at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:126650:35)
> at QueryClientProvider (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:125219:21) overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:4045 printWarning @
> vendor.js:90934 error @ vendor.js:90910 validateFunctionComponentInDev
> @ vendor.js:108793 mountIndeterminateComponent @ vendor.js:108760
> beginWork @ vendor.js:109916 beginWork$1 @ vendor.js:114802
> performUnitOfWork @ vendor.js:113638 workLoopSync @ vendor.js:113569
> renderRootSync @ vendor.js:113532 performSyncWorkOnRoot @
> vendor.js:113155 (anonymous) @ vendor.js:102194
> unstable_runWithPriority @ vendor.js:137947 runWithPriority$1 @
> vendor.js:102143 flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ vendor.js:102189
> flushSyncCallbackQueue @ vendor.js:102176 flushPassiveEffectsImpl @
> vendor.js:114482 unstable_runWithPriority @ vendor.js:137947
> runWithPriority$1 @ vendor.js:102143 flushPassiveEffects @
> vendor.js:114309 (anonymous) @ vendor.js:114186 workLoop @
> vendor.js:137896 flushWork @ vendor.js:137869 performWorkUntilDeadline
> @ vendor.js:137636

Any ideas how to fix this?